# One thousand raffle tickets are sold

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

> The scenario is: One thousand raffle tickets are sold. There is a grand prize of \$300, 3 second prizes of \$100, and 6 third prizes of \$50.  A person purchased one raffle ticket. Find the probability that the person wins at least \$100.

I am thinking that let X denote the amount of money the person wins from the raffle. I am interested in finding $P(X \geq 100)$ (if I am correct). Since the person only buys one raffle, then this turns out to be the probability the person wins either the grand prize or the second prize category, not the third prize because even if the person won that prize, he or she could only win at most 50$. Therefore, the probability I am looking at is (1/1000) + (2/1000); this is incorrect. I am not sure why.

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct, but overlooked that there are 3 prices of $100 (not 2). Inessential error.

Comment: I got it now. I am so silly. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: @drhab Why did you put that as a comment? Comments aren't for answering.

Comment: @Arthur I admit it is inconsistent. If it concerns something small in my view (as I said: inessential error) then I tend to give a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you made a mistake: How many \$100 prizes are there? What's the probability of winning one?

Comment: There are 3 prizes of $100, so the probability of winning one is 1/3. Right?

Comment: Yes, there are three of them. But there are 1000 tickets in total. What is the probability that the ticket that the person bought is one of the \$100 prize winning ones?